# Adding image to Excel

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, epplus

I'm trying to insert an image from file to Excel using EPPlus and vb.net, I added the image to Excel successfully but can't position it properly.

```
Using img As System.Drawing.Image = Image.FromFile(path)
    ws.Drawings.AddPicture("picture1", img)
    ws.Drawings.Item("picture1").SetPosition(row, 0, column, 0)
End Using
```

That's how I add the image, you can see the results in the image below. You can clearly see where I wanted the images.

[image: Excel]

Comment: What values are in the `row` and `column` variables? From your output it looks like they're both one higher than they should be. Trying changing `ws.Drawings.Item("picture1").SetPosition(row, 0, column, 0)` to be `ws.Drawings.Item("picture1").SetPosition(row - 1, 0, column - 1, 0)` and see if that yields better results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I just have to adjust the position of the picture by changing these 2 values

```
ws.Drawings.Item("picture1").SetPosition(row, -27, column, -27)
```

Just have to play around with the values to get the position you want.